# WPF resource merged to Application.Resources but not resolved at runtime

Tags: wpf, resources, resourcedictionary

I have a brush that is part of a `ResourceDictionary` that is merged to `Application.Resources`.

But for some reason it's not resolved at runtime when a style is being applied to one of the controls. However, if I call Application.Current.FindResource("BrushName") from the Immediate Window at the time when exception is thrown, the resource is found.

Am I missing something? Isn't WPF supposed to try to look for the resource in the app's resources?

**UPDATE**
The application is quite big, so I can't post all actual code but here's the way the resources are merged and used:

`Brushes.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushName" Color="#12345678" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`SomeStyles.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
  <Style x:Key="SomeStyle">
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="{StaticResource BrushName}" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

`App.xaml`

```
<Application ...>
  <Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="SomeStyles.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>


  </Application.Resources>
</Application ...>
```

And then some control might use the style using the resource like this:

```
...
Style={StaticResource SomeStyle}
...
```

**UPDATE**

It seems to happen to menus and controls that are created in code. Can it be related to those controls and menus not being parts of any window's visual tree?

Comment: Could you post some code of how your merging the dictionary.

Comment: I have replicated your sample here and it builds and runs correctly for me, it seems the issue is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Any luck to get an answer on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SomeStyle.xaml dictionary needs to reference Brushes.xaml dictionary directly, like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Brushes.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  <Style x:Key="SomeStyle">
    <Setter Property="SomeProperty" Value="{StaticResource BrushName}" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

StaticResources only search up the tree of the current dictionary, so you need to pass in any resources that it needs to reference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DynamicResource in the XAML mark up extension?

Your xaml should be {DynamicResource brushName} not {StaticResource brushName}

Comment: Yes it does hit performance, but the reason it hits performance is because it has a greater lookup scope. StaticResource only works if the resource is with in the current scope at compile time, DynamicResource will do the scope look up to run time. Performance hit will be induced but at least it will work.

Comment: Well, I understand why it hits performance. The problem is that Application resources are supposed to always be in "current scope"...

Comment: Hm my mistake, I thought application resources required a look up. I have just tested this and you are right.